# Regex to match a string and ignore case sensitivity

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex that can match the word "Model" or "model" or "MODEL" - it should not match "oneModel" or any word that has model in it.

`^([model]{5,10})$`

I cannot find an example for this, I am trying to validate a text field that has to be inside  `^([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10})$` as part of this [plugin's requirement](https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/format/#kb-regular-expression-validation).

Comment: `\b(?:[Mm]odel|MODEL)\b`

Comment: thanks @Aaron I never mastered regex, this worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `i` flag ([read more here](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction)) for regex to ignore case

using your noted regex `/^([model]{5,10})$/i`

`string.match("^([model]{5,10})$", "i")`

if you want ONLY model then you only need `/^model$/i`

that will match model / Model / MODEL / mOdeL

Comment: Note that relying on case-insensivity will make you match more cases that the 3 listed by OP, such as `modeL` or `mOdEl`

Comment: `[model]{5,10}` matches `mmlledo` or `mmmmmmmmmm`.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for may vary depending on what you are looking for.
For example if you are looking for this specific word in a full text:

```
/\bmodel\b/i
```

this will return true in this text:

```
this is a MoDel // return true
this is not oneModelTwo // return false
```

You can test all of your regex (with full explanation of what does what) on this site :
[regex 101](https://regex101.com)